# Its saying abi and evm is undefined when compiled

Tags: solidity, abi

I have the following:

```
solc = require("solc");
fs =require("fs");


Web3 = require("web3");
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:yyyy"));

let fileContent = fs.readFileSync("demo.sol").toString();
console.log(fileContent);

var input = {
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: {
      "demo.sol": {
        content: fileContent,
      },
    },
  
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        "*": {
          "*": ["*"],
        },
      },
    },
};  

var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
console.log(output);

ABI = output.contracts["demo.sol"]["demo"].abi;
bytecode = output.contracts["demo.sol"]["demo"].evm.bytecode.object;
```

Answer (score 0):

//try this code it work for me

const solc = require("solc");

// file system - read and write files to your computer
const fs = require("fs");

// web3 interface
const Web3 = require("web3");

// setup a http provider
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"));

// reading the file contents of the smart  contract

const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("demo.sol").toString();
// console.log(fileContent);

// create an input structure for my solidity compiler
var input = {
language: "Solidity",
sources: {
"demo.sol": {
content: fileContent,
},
},

settings: {
outputSelection: {
"*": {
"*": ["*"],
},
},
},
};

var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
// console.log("Output: ", output);

const ABI = output.contracts["demo.sol"]["Demo"].abi;
const byteCode = output.contracts["demo.sol"]["Demo"].evm.bytecode.object;

// console.log("abi: ",ABI)
// console.log("byte code: ",byteCode)

Comment: Can you format the code properly in the code block to improve readability?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ABI = output.contracts["demo.sol"].demo.abi;
bytecode = output.contracts["demo.sol"].demo.evm.bytecode.object;
```